# explicit implementation doesn't work in my case

Tags: c#, interface

I don't quite understand how explicit implementation works, so I made a mockup

```
public class ShoppingCart : IEnumerable<Product>
{
   public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator()
   {
      return Products.GetEnumerator(); 
   }
   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() //why 'public' is not needed?
   {
      return GetEnumerator(); // why there is not any error here?
   }
}
```

Below is my mockup:

```
class MockUp: Ilayer1
  {
    public string testMethod()
    {
      return "Layer1";
    }

    string Ilayer2.testMethod()  // error, not all code path return a value
    {
      testMethod();
    }
  }

  interface Ilayer1 : Ilayer2
  {
    string testMethod();
  }

  interface Ilayer2
  {
    string testMethod();
  }
```

but I have a compilation error, but why there is no error for ShoppingCart?

And how can I make my MockUp class work?

Comment: you are missing a `return` in `Ilayer2.testMethod()`. Try `return testMethod();`

Comment: Or `string Ilayer2.testMethod() => testMethod();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer the questions one after one:

> why 'public' is not needed?

Since if we put `public` we'll have an *ambiguity*:

```
public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator() {...}

public IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {...}
```

And in case of `ShoppingCart.GetEnumerator();` which method will be executed? That's why explicit interface implementation is effectively `private`

```
// public
public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator() {...}

// private
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {...}
```

So far so good in case of `ShoppingCart.GetEnumerator();` we call the only `public` method (with no ambiguity). In case of `(ShoppingCart as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();` we call an *interface implementation* whatever it is (again we have only one method which fits).

> I have a compilation error, but why there is no error for
>   ShoppingCart?

```
string Ilayer2.testMethod()  // error, not all code path return a value
{
  testMethod();
}
```

The method should return `string`, but it doesn't do it. Add `return`:

```
string Ilayer2.testMethod()  // error, not all code path return a value
{
   return testMethod();
}
```

Or even

```
string Ilayer2.testMethod() => testMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. for `ShoppingCart as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();` why do we need to perform casting?

Comment: @amjad: If we want to call `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` we can't do it without *cast* - the method is `private`. We we cast to `IEnumerable` we call *interface's* method and interface's methods are all `public`